# event.preventDefault() does not on Android tablets using touchstart

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a responsive drop down, for tablet users i am cancelling the click so the drop down menu using event.preventDefault()
This works fine on ipad but does not on Android. The function itself works as I have done some testing but the event.preventDefault() does not cancel the click. I have tried with a return false instead but it does not work for me either.
I have seen quiet a few posts relating but could not find a solution to this.
The javascript I am using is:

```
$("#nav li a").on({ 'touchstart' : function(event) { 
        //if there is a submenu we cancel the click to show the drop down
        if (String($(this).parent().find('ul').html())!='undefined')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});//end of touch event
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your event may be bubbling up the dom, try event.stopPropagation();
Also look at the double tap plugin, i had this problem before as well.

[Demo](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly)

Comment: Thanks eg_dac, the event bubbling was the issue and it is sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try checking `touchend` as well - Android gave us some funky behavior with `preventDefault` as well. Also, if your problem is that this is happening on an anchor, consider replacing the anchor's href with javascript:void(0);</strike>

```
Instead of this:
<a href="#">Open Menu</a>

Do this:
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Open Menu</a>
```

Touch events live through a whole life cycle, and it doesn't look like `preventDefault` has anything to do with stopping further events (`touchmove`, `touchend`, etc).

You can also look into jQuery's `vclick` event, which attempts to water down mouse click events and touch events into one similar event, but you should definitely read the notes and warnings http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: Thank you but I have a mixed of links some top links with an anchor and some with an actual URL.

Comment: Sorry, @user1620090, I just noticed that `vclick` is only in jQuery Mobile. A coworker has been putting it everywhere in our desktop sites  (`'click vclick'`) so I just assumed...made an ass out of "u" and "me" - really just me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps on Android the `touchend` or `click` event is fired as well. Have you tried adding these events to your listener? Try this:

```
$("#nav li a").on({ 'touchstart touchend click' : function(event){ 
   if (String($(this).parent().find('ul').html())!='undefined'){
       event.preventDefault();
   }
}});
```